# How do I limit the number of entries in a java hashtable?

Tags: java, hashtable

Is there a technique such that I can specify a number n such that when the (n + 1)th entry is inserted, the oldest entry is removed first ensuring that the size of the hashtable is always limited to n?

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272674/what-is-a-data-structure-kind-of-like-a-hash-table-but-infrequently-used-keys-ar. The question provides a solution.

Comment: @robhruska - do you think this counts as a duplicate?  I'm on the fence.

Comment: I'm not sure. The perspectives are a bit different, since this question is asking about a "size limit" while the other question targets "infrequently used" entries. I'm not opposed to leaving it open, if just so that there's more searchability for those looking at it from this question's angle.

Comment: http://letmegooglethatforyou.com/?q=data+structures

Answer (score 28):

[LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) does exactly that, see javadoc for the [removeEldestEntry](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)) method.

Something like this should do the trick, this will remove the oldest inserted entry:

```
Map map = new LinkedHashMap() {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry eldest) {
        return size() > N;
    }
};
```

You can also remove oldest accessed entry by specifying it in the constructor:

```
    Map map = new LinkedHashMap(16, 0.75f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry eldest) {
            return size() > N;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a [LRU cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) perhaps? Here's a blog post on one based on [LinkedHashMap](http://www.khanspot.com/2006/11/27/a-simple-lru-cache-in-5-lines/).

Comment: I came here to mention LinkedHashMap, which I used for a LRU cache recently.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Apache Collections. They have a bunch of LRU implementations. Otherwise, you can easily write a similar wrapper for the standard library collections; I don't think there's one you can use directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a double-ended queue, or [Deque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deque), and just remove the first item when you're at the max count.

Answer (score 0):

If you have concurrency needs, don't try to solve this problem yourself. Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) has a .maximumSize() method that allows you to limit the size of a map, although it's my understanding that old entries may be cleaned out before you actually reach the limit.

There's [an interesting page](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/Design) on the data structure's design, which should impress on the reader how difficult it would be to do any better than Google's implementation. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're caching you could use a WeakHashMap or WeakReference and then not have to worry about the size of the cache.

Comment: Just to clarify to avoid propagating a common misconception: WeakHashMap is NOT suitable for LRU caching by itself; it uses WeakReferences for KEYS, not VALUES. It's ideal for keeping metadata about objects which don't 'belong' to you; not for assuming entries will be thrown out when memory runs out