# How to limit the number of entries in a java List?

Tags: java

I know how to limit size in Map ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422181/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-entries-in-a-java-hashtable),using LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry method does exactly that)

I want to know how to limit size in a List,what is a best way to implement?

thanks for help :)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the size limit is exceeded? (should the add fail? should elements be removed to make room? if you want to remove elements, what's the criteria for removal?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define a fixed-size list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207162/define-a-fixed-size-list-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the java.util.Collections class source and develop a SizeLimitedList similar to how they do a checkedList.  Then on add I would delete the first entry from the list if the list was full.

Comment: `if(list.size()>10){list.remove(0);}` like this?

Comment: you would do that in the overridden add method.  you would need to look at addAll too.

Comment: You could just derive from ArrayList, and override add and addAll and do the above.

Answer (score 14):

You could try create a new list with streams. If are only 10 don't should be a performance problem create a new list.

```
list = list.stream().limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> b = a.size() > 10 ? new ArrayList<>(a.subList(0, 10)) : a;
```

Comment: That throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the source list is too small.

Comment: You need additional "if" in case source list is too small.

Comment: Added a ternary operator instead of if to the example.