# Define a fixed-size list in Java

Tags: java, list, collections

Is it possible to define a list with a fixed size that's 100? If not why isn't this available in Java?

Comment: You can set the starting size of an ArrayList but if you add more elements it will expand itself

Comment: fixed, or maximum? Do you want the list to not be able to have more than 100 items? And what should happen if `add()` is attempted? Exception, nothing, or an existing element discarded in favour of the new one.

Comment: Aren't these beasts called "arrays"?

Comment: arrays do not conform to the `List` interface ;)

Comment: @Bozho: no they don't but given the limited information available in his question, who knows if he needs that, and they're plenty powerful.   If all he needs is some collection to hold 100 items, no more and no less, then he can do well with an array.  If not, he needs to clarify his question **a lot**.

Comment: @fasatcoderjava - will you clarify the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed Size List in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027995/fixed-size-list-in-java)

Comment: List<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(100);

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## `FixedSizeList`

**Yes**,

The [*Apache Commons*](https://commons.apache.org/collections/) library provides the [`FixedSizeList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/FixedSizeList.html) class which does not support the `add`, `remove` and `clear` methods (but the set method is allowed because it does not modify the `List`'s size). Ditto for [`FixedSizeList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/11.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/FixedSizeList.html) in [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/). If you try to call one of these methods, your list remains the same size.

To create your fixed size list, just call

```
List<YourType> fixed = FixedSizeList.decorate(Arrays.asList(new YourType[100]));
```

---

You can use [`unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) if you want an unmodifiable view of the specified list, or **read-only access to internal lists**.

```
List<YourType> unmodifiable = java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(internalList);
```

Comment: Why will you decorate Arrays.asList result if it is already a fixed size list?

Comment: Yea ... the `FixedSizeList.decorate(...)` is for wrapping lists that are not already fixed sized.   Using it here is redundant.

Answer (score 64):

This should do it if memory serves:

```
List<MyType> fixed = Arrays.asList(new MyType[100]);
```

Comment: will it keep the size to 100 if you keep adding to it?

Comment: @fastcodejava - you cannot use the `add` method with a fixed-length list - it already has 100 null entries. Use `set` to set values.

Comment: It can set fixed size. But when I add the object to the List<>, I always received ERROR UNKOWN, u know why?

Comment: @AlexTran - read the comments.  You cannot call `add` on a list created this way.

Comment: This doesn't work if `MyType` is a parameterized type. For instance, `List<List<String>> fixed = Arrays.asList(new List<String>[100]);` will generate a compiler error. (In earlier Java versions, it generated a warning.) See [Restrictions on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html) in the Java tutorials.

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` always creates an immutable list.

Comment: @Daithi - not correct, documentation states "fixed-size list", its elements **can** be changed, just the size not

Answer (score 36):

A Java list is a collection of objects ... the elements of a list.  The size of the list is the number of elements in that list.  If you want that size to be fixed, that means that you cannot either add or remove elements, because adding or removing elements would violate your "fixed size" constraint.

The simplest way to implement a "fixed sized" list (if that is really what you want!) is to put the elements into an array and then `Arrays.asList(array)` to create the list wrapper.  The wrapper will allow you to do operations like `get` and `set`, but the `add` and `remove` operations will throw exceptions.

And if you want to create a fixed-sized wrapper for an existing list, then you could use the Apache commons [`FixedSizeList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/FixedSizeList.html) class.  But note that this wrapper can't stop something else changing the size of the original list, and if that happens the wrapped list will presumably reflect those changes.

---

On the other hand, if you really want a list type with a fixed limit (or limits) on its size, then you'll need to create your own List class to implement this.  For example, you could create a wrapper class that implements the relevant checks in the various `add` / `addAll` and `remove` / `removeAll` / `retainAll` operations.  (And in the iterator `remove` methods if they are supported.)

So why doesn't the Java Collections framework implement these?  Here's why I think so:

1. Use-cases that need this are rare.
2. The use-cases where this is needed, there are different requirements on what to do when an operation tries to break the limits; e.g. throw exception, ignore operation, discard some other element to make space.
3. A list implementation with limits could be problematic for helper methods; e.g. `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 18):

Yes. You can pass a java array to [Arrays.asList(Object[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28java.lang.Object[]%29).

```
List<String> fixedSizeList = Arrays.asList(new String[100]);
```

You cannot insert new Strings to the fixedSizeList (it already has 100 elements). You can only set its values like this:

```
fixedSizeList.set(7, "new value");
```

That way you have a fixed size list. The thing functions like an array and I can't think of a good reason to use it. I'd love to hear why you want your fixed size collection to be a list instead of just using an array.

Comment: My reason's the same as Jeffrey's. Shocked to learn that you cant have the line:
T[] myGenericArray = new T[5];

Comment: This is perfect. Instead of "String" we have to put the Object class as per requirement.Thanx.

Answer (score 11):

Typically an alternative for fixed size Lists are Java arrays. Lists by default are allowed to grow/shrink in Java. However, that does not mean you cannot have a List of a fixed size. You'll need to do some work and create a custom implementation.

You can extend an [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) with custom implementations of the clear, add and remove methods.

e.g.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FixedSizeList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public FixedSizeList(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            super.add(null);
        }
    }

    public FixedSizeList(T[] initialElements) {
        super(initialElements.length);
        for (T loopElement : initialElements) {
            super.add(loopElement);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Elements may not be cleared from a fixed size List.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Elements may not be added to a fixed size List, use set() instead.");
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Elements may not be added to a fixed size List, use set() instead.");
    }

    @Override
    public T remove(int index) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Elements may not be removed from a fixed size List.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Elements may not be removed from a fixed size List.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Elements may not be removed from a fixed size List.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create an array of size 100. If you need the List interface, then call [Arrays.asList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) on it. It'll return a fixed-size list backed by the array.

Answer (score 3):

If you want some flexibility, create a class that watches the size of the list.

Here's a simple example. You would need to override all the methods that change the state of the list.

```
public class LimitedArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T>{
    private int limit;

    public LimitedArrayList(int limit){
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T item){
        if (this.size() > limit)
            throw new ListTooLargeException();
        super.add(item);
    }

    // ... similarly for other methods that may add new elements ...
```

Comment: The add(int index, T element) method will also need to be overridden.

Comment: @shams: That's why I said "you would need to override all the methods that change the state of the list" ...

Comment: Yeah, I think handling these two should suffice. The add* are the only methods from the standard interface that can increase the size of the List. I think there are four of them but the other two (addAll*) in turn call the add* methods.

Comment: @shams: Good point, but I'm not sure I would depend on that, as there is no contract saying that the others must depend on the simple add(). To be safe, I would override all four add methods.

Comment: True, but in the ArrayList impl it does use the add() calls and LimitedArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> :). In general however all the four add methods will need to be overridden.

Comment: The check should be:
 this.size() == limit

Comment: @shams - wrong! At least Java 16 (Oracle Corporation, 16, 2021-03-16) implementation of `ArrayList#addAll` **does not** call `add`! It checks and eventually grows the array and uses `System.arraycopy` to add the values! (also Java 8 does **not** use `add`)

Comment: @shams - Source [ArrayList#addAll](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L669)  -  the method from `AbstractList` is being overriden by `ArrayList` !

Answer (score 3):

You can define a generic function like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<T> newFixedSizeList(int size) {
    return (List<T>)Arrays.asList(new Object[size]);
}
```

And

```
List<String> s = newFixedSizeList(3);  // All elements are initialized to null
s.set(0, "zero");
s.add("three");  // throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work pretty nicely. It will never grow beyond the initial size. The toList method will give you the entries in the correct chronological order. This was done in groovy - but converting it to java proper should be pretty easy.

```
static class FixedSizeCircularReference<T> {
    T[] entries
    FixedSizeCircularReference(int size) {
        this.entries = new Object[size] as T[]
        this.size = size
    }
    int cur = 0
    int size
    void add(T entry) {
        entries[cur++] = entry
        if (cur >= size) {
            cur = 0
        }
    }
    List<T> asList() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>()
        int oldest = (cur == size - 1) ? 0 : cur
        for (int i = 0; i < this.entries.length; i++) {
            def e = this.entries[oldest + i < size ? oldest + i : oldest + i - size]
            if (e) list.add(e)
        }
        return list
    }
}

FixedSizeCircularReference<String> latestEntries = new FixedSizeCircularReference(100)
latestEntries.add('message 1') 
// .....
latestEntries.add('message 1000') 
latestEntries.asList() //Returns list of '100' messages
```

Answer (score 1):

You need either of the following depending on the type of the container of `T` elements you pass to the builder (`Collection<T>` or `T[]`):

- In case of an existing `Collection<T> YOUR_COLLECTION`:

> ```java
> Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(YOUR_COLLECTION));
> ```

- In case of an existing `T[] YOUR_ARRAY`:

> ```java
> Arrays.asList(YOUR_ARRAY);
> ```

***Simple as that***

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), it seems that the answer is no. Although there are some classes in java that you can set them fixed size, like [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), ArrayList and LinkedList can't, because there is no constructor for these two to specify capacity.

If you want to stick to ArrayList/LinkedList, one easy solution is to check the size manually each time.

```
public void fixedAdd(List<Integer> list, int val, int size) {
    list.add(val);
    if(list.size() > size) list.remove(0);
}
```

LinkedList is better than ArrayList in this situation. Suppose there are many values to be added but the list size is quite samll, there will be many remove operations. The reason is that the cost of removing from ArrayList is O(N), but only O(1) for LinkedList.

Comment: 1: `PriorityQueue` grows if needed, it is **not** fixed size ([ideone](https://ideone.com/nFOoSh)); 2: not sure if that matters, but `PriorityQueue` does not implement `List`

Answer (score 0):

The public `java.util.List` subclasses of the JDK don't provide a fixed size feature that   doesn't make part of the [`List` specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).
You could find it only in `Queue` subclasses (for example `ArrayBlockingQueue`, a bounded blocking queue backed by an array for example) that handle very specific requirements.

In Java, with a `List` type, you could implement it according to two scenarios :

1) The fixed list size is always both the actual and the maximum size.

It sounds as an array definition. So `Arrays.asList()` that returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array is what you are looking for. And as with an array you can neither increase nor decrease its size but only changing its content. So adding and removing operation are not supported.

For example :

```
Foo[] foosInput= ...;
List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(foosInput);
foos.add(new Foo()); // throws an Exception
foos.remove(new Foo()); // throws an Exception
```

It works also with a collection as input while first we convert it into an array :

```
Collection<Foo> foosInput= ...;
List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(foosInput.toArray(Foo[]::new)); // Java 11 way
// Or
List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(foosInput.stream().toArray(Foo[]::new)); // Java 8 way
```

2) The list content is not known as soon as its creation. So you mean by fixed size list  its maximum size.

You could use inheritance (`extends ArrayList`) but you should favor composition over that since it allows you to not couple your class with the implementation details of this implementation and provides also flexibility about the implementation of the decorated/composed.

With [Guava Forwarding classes](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained) you could do :

```
import com.google.common.collect.ForwardingList;

public class FixedSizeList<T> extends ForwardingList<T> {

  private final List<T> delegate;
  private final int maxSize;

  public FixedSizeList(List<T> delegate, int maxSize) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
  }

  @Override protected List<T> delegate() {
    return delegate;
  }

  @Override public boolean add(T element) {
    assertMaxSizeNotReached(1);
    return super.add(element);
  }

  @Override public void add(int index, T element) {
    assertMaxSizeNotReached(1);
    super.add(index, element);
  }

  @Override public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> collection) {
    assertMaxSizeNotReached(collection.size());
    return super.addAll(collection);
  }

  @Override public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> elements) {
    assertMaxSizeNotReached(elements.size());
    return super.addAll(index, elements);
  }    

  private void assertMaxSizeNotReached(int size) {
    if (delegate.size() + size >= maxSize) {
      throw new RuntimeException("size max reached");
    }
  }

}
```

And use it :

```
List<String> fixedSizeList = new FixedSizeList<>(new ArrayList<>(), 3); 
fixedSizeList.addAll(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
fixedSizeList.add("4");  // throws an Exception
```

Note that with composition, you could use it with any `List` implementation :

```
List<String> fixedSizeList = new FixedSizeList<>(new LinkedList<>(), 3); 
//...
```

Which is not possible with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

To get a fixed-size list, you can simply use the Stream API. This will result in a fixed-size list :

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(new int[100])
                            .boxed()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or the old-fashioned way, This will result in a fixed-size list that is backed by the specified array:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[100]);
```

Comment: No, the API of [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) states that "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, [...] of the List returned", so the returned list may support adding more elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, especially if you only want a fixed size internal data source (e.g. in a wrapper class) that is generic, is to use an `ArrayList` initialized to `null`:

```
List<MyGenericType<E>> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(size, null));
```

Checking if a value is set or not consists of checking for null:

```
if (list.get(index) == null)
    // Not set
```

Setting a value must be done using `set(index, ...)`. Removing would mean setting back to `null` with `set(index, null)`. For stream handling, you might want to add an extra `filter(Objects::nonNull)` to only get "set" values.

You can do add and remove and break the fixed size, so this list cannot be exposed to the world outside the wrapper class unless it's made unmodifiable.

This is an easier way to create an internal "array" with some nice handling of values and without the extra memory burden of an `Integer`-keyed `Map`. Though, `Arrays.asList(...)` may still be just as fine for your purposes.

Answer (score -3):

Yes is posible:

```
List<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(100);
```

now, the initial capacity of myArrayList will be 100

Comment: This one sets the capacity, not the size.

Comment: It's like one liter bottle. You determine how much water is inside, but the maximum capacity remains 1 liter. The size can be 0 to 100 is just up to you.

Comment: wrong, if more space is needed, the *bottle* will be exchanged with a larger one! Or why is the constructor parameter called **initial**Capacity? Documentation *"...As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically...."* (check the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L467)) ((or just test it [ideone](https://ideone.com/aP6YAD)...))