# Setting size to TreeSet

Tags: java

Is there a way to give size limit to TreeSet in Java Collections as we do for arrays?
for example in arrays we do,

```
anArray = new int[10];
```

Comment: what do you mean a "size limit"
Can you give us partial code?

Comment: No - you might want to check this [FixedSizeSortedSet](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/FixedSizeSortedSet.htm) - no guarantee that it is bug free... Actually it does not override addAll so might not work as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can come to an existing collection with capacity limits is a BlockingQueue.   When adding items to the queue, you can specify a zero second (or very small) blocking timeout, so that an exception is thrown when the capacity is exceeded.  For more details, see [BlockingQueue.offer()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer%28E,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Answer (score 5):

An array has a fixed length that must be specified when you create it.

A `TreeSet` automatically grows as you add elements to it. You cannot set its size. You can only read it.

Answer (score 3):

This threat can help you [fixed size list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207162/fixed-size-list-in-java)

Also, you can implement your own collection in order to add elements if your limit has not been reached

Answer (score 2):

None of TreeSet's constructors specifies an initial size, it grows when elements are added. And there's no way to limit the maximum size of the data structure. Every time you add() a new element, you'd need to manually check if it has exceeded the maximum size allowed. You can specify this behavior by implementing a subclass that extends from TreeSet and overriding add(), addAll(), and the two constructors that receive a Collection as a parameter.

Comment: as shown by the answer that tries to do that, it is not necessarily an easy thing. Typically, if you set has 9 items and you addAll a collection of 2, you need to check for duplicates before you decide if you addAll or not, in which case you still need to add one etc.

Comment: @assylias that's right, there _are_ implementation details to take care of, but the general idea holds: subclass TreeSet and program the fixed size limit - if it's in the OP's interest, he'll have to decide how to handle the edge cases

Answer (score 2):

You can always make your own implementation.  Here is an example to get you started; you may find that you wish to tweak it accordingly:

```
public class BoundedTreeSet<E> extends TreeSet<E> {

    private final int limit;

    public BoundedTreeSet(final int limit) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public BoundedTreeSet(final int limit, final Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public BoundedTreeSet(final int limit, final Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        super(comparator);
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public BoundedTreeSet(final int limit, final SortedSet<E> s) {
        super(s);
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final E e) {
        if (size() >= limit) {
            return false;
        }

        return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        if (size() + c.size() >= limit) {
            return false;
        }

        return super.addAll(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: your addAll has a bug (if size() == N-1 and c.size() == 2 for example). Bottom line: not that easy to make it bug free + in that case, if c contains an item already in the list, you can actually addAll(c)...

Comment: Fixed.  No one said it was easy to make it bug-free ;)  The set of things that are easy to keep bug-free is quite small...

Comment: At first sight yes. Your addAll is still buggy.

Comment: Also you would presumably spend more than 5 minutes writing something like this if you were to use it for real.  This is for instruction's sake, to provide an example as to how you can approach implementing such a solution.  As I noted in the answer, some tweaking may be necessary.

Comment: I understand but I'm trying to make the point that it is more complicated than it looks.

Comment: I don't think that just because the solution is "difficult" it should be avoided.  In the scope of things that one has to program to create a working application, I wouldn't say that subclassing `TreeSet` is one of the hardest...  Yes, bugs will happen.  But you spend time developing and you test, as with anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of `BoundedTreeSet` in Apache Solr, which keeps the biggest values when trying to insert into a "full" set :

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/BoundedTreeSet.html

Maven artifact available here :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
   <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```