# Initialize the maximum size of a TreeSet that is sorted with a comparator class

Tags: comparator, treeset

I was creating an ordered TreeSet with a Comparator class. However I have a doubt: how can I initialize the maximum size of a TreeSet, when I initialize it with a Comparator class?
In my example I would like a TreeSet subscribers of maximum size 50.

```
this.clienti = new TreeSet <T> (new StructureByNumeroClienteComparator <AbstractCliente> ());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658882/setting-size-to-treeset Maybe you can check some of the answers here.

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for. Thank you @NagulanS