# Collections with limited size

Tags: java, collections

Is there any collection which allows me limit the number of elements allowed?

What I need is a collection with size of 5 elements, when this collection is full, a new element can be added, but the oldest element of this collection will be replaced for the new element.

Comment: What do you mean? So for example you want to have a list that can only have at most 5 elements, and any attempt to add more will throw an exception?

Comment: Would that work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5207170/1362049

Comment: Please specify a use case. The most simple solution is the Good Old Java Array :)

Comment: What type of collection you are talking about?

Comment: Do you mean a data structure that gives an error if you try to overfill it, or one that throws away one of the existing values to fit a newly added one?

Comment: An array is a type of collection so that will do.

Comment: I need to do a collection with size of 5 elements, when this collection is full, a new element can be added, but the oldest element of this collection will be replaced for the new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend an old good ArrayList (or any other implementation which fits you the best).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LimitedCollection<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public static final int MAX_ELEMENTS = 2;

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (this.size() < MAX_ELEMENTS) {
            return super.add(e);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, your solution seem great, I will work with it.

Comment: Your class should be named LimitedArrayList as you extend an array list and whats more you should also override the addAll and constructors.

Comment: That doesn't remove the oldest element upon addition a new one when the List reached the limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with majority of the Collections available in **java.utils package**.
You can do this,sample for List Collection:

```
List<X> list = Arrays.asList(new X[desiredSize]);
// where X is any Object type (including arrays and enums,
// but excluding primitives)
```

The resulting list is modifiable, but not resizable (i.e. add(e) and remove(e) don't work,        but set(index, e) does).

Answer (score 0):

Either [Guava EvictingQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html) or [Apache common-collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html) should do the job for you.