# Android:how to have an Array of type ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

Hey basically what I wish to do is take a number of `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` menuItems and pass it to my `onPostExecute` method so to do this I intended to create an array of menuItems and pass it through...this is the code I used to do this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>[] arr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>[6];
                arr[0] = menuItems;
                arr[1] = menuItems2;
                arr[2] = menuItems3;
                arr[3] = menuItems4;
                arr[4] = menuItems5;
                arr[5] = menuItems6;
```

then I return arr. However I am getting this error

```
Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

which seems to indicate something about Java implementing its Generics at complier level which is about all I was able to find after researching questions on stack overflow and on the web in general. So my question is simply how would I do this? Either a way to solve my error or a different method of returning the menuItems.

Comment: Lists are not arrays

`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();`
`arr.add(menuItems);`
`arr.add(menuItems2);`
`//...`

Comment: Create `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists` instead of `[]` of `ArrayLists`.

Comment: The method add(HashMap<String,String>) in the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> - this is my next error on add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible ArrayList is itself a dynamic array part of Collection Framework [refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) the docs.
Remove the [] bracket from your code.
Quote from WikiPedia.

> In computer science, a dynamic array, growable array, resizable array,
>   dynamic table, mutable array, or array list is a random access,
>   variable-size list data structure that allows elements to be added or
>   removed. It is supplied with standard libraries in many modern
>   mainstream programming languages.

Also [refer this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html) a very good resource fro beginners.
If you want to have fixed size ArrayList [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207162/fixed-size-list-in-java).

for eg What I suggest.
**EDIT**

```
ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>> list =new ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>>()
Hashmap<String,String> map=new Hasmap<String,String>()
map.put("KEY","VALUE");
list.add(map);
```

**Remember you should each time you have to create new instance for hashmap. Because it use unique value**

Comment: okay thanks i will try this. Also thanks for reference id like to also learn from my mistakes

Comment: @james Question needs to be at least 15 minute old before OP will be able to accept answer :)

Comment: great thanks very much this works perfectly ill choose this as the answer once im allowed

Comment: sorry how would i then get the menuItems back into separate ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> types?

Comment: sorry the question still stands once ive returned this how would i then get the menuItems back. I know how to do this with an array but this is new to me

Comment: @ChronosChris do u want to display or assign to a variable

Comment: @james its okay instead of this i turned the menuItems.toString and just returned as a String array then assigned to variables as that was my final intent anyways

Comment: @ChronosChris I didn't get that will u ellaborate. Noramally we can pass it using intent

Comment: @ChronosChris I was busy at workplace so I was unable to answer u

Comment: @james once i had the values in the menuItems ArrayList i then wanted to return it as a ArrayList and then convert to string so i could split and get the individual values so i could them for calculation so say i has 1,5,6 returned from my RSS feed i then wanted to make these string then convert them to int and use them in a calculation. Maybe i actually made this harder than was needed but it works correctly

Comment: @ChronosChris use the book of Herbert Schildt its the best book for every java programmer. Enjoy Coding

Comment: @james thanks for the reference! i will definitely give that a read

Answer (score 2):

You [cannot create arrays of parameterized types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays).

Your best choice is to use List instead of array. Also while creating references you should [prefer interface over actual class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

```
List<List<Map<String, String>>> list = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>;
list.add(menuItems1);
list.add(menuItems2);
list.add(menuItems3);
list.add(menuItems4);
list.add(menuItems5);
list.add(menuItems6);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>[] arr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>[6];
```

You are trying to create an `array` of `ArrayList`. Is that on purpose or...?
ArrayLists by default are expandable. Try removing the `[]` and `[6]`

Then, use the `add()` method to add the data you want :)