# About declaring a new List in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, constructor

Let's suppose I want to declare a `List of AbstractClass`, and each of its elements must be mixed children of `AbstractClass`, called `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` (which are not abstract, by the way). But I also want it **of a specific size.**

So I declare

```
List <AbstractClass> list = new ArrayList <AbstractClass> (SIZE);
```

If I add elements the to list using

```
list.add(new SubClass1());
list.add(new SubClass2());
```

are they going to be added **at the end of the array** or **starting from index=0**?
In the first case, do I have to manually add elements with a loop, like this?

```
List <AbstractClass> list = new ArrayList <AbstractClass> (); //I've removed size
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
list.add(new SubClass1());
list.add(new SubClass2());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are they going to be added at the end of the array or starting from index=0?

Both.  The `SIZE` argument to the `ArrayList` constructor determines its initial capacity, not its initial length.  Once this `ArrayList` is constructed, it has a capacity of `SIZE` but a size of `0`.  The first element `add`ed will be index `0`, the second will be index `1`, and so on.

If you don't supply an initial capacity, there will a default initial capacity.

> In the first case, do I have to manually add elements with a loop, like this?

No method calls in general have to be in any loop.

Answer (score 1):

The List interface is not intended for fixed size arrays: as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207162/fixed-size-list-in-java) here already. You can set an initial size however.

About adding: from the official [Java 7 List docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

> The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list
>   each element is inserted.
>
> `add(E e)` –
>   Appends the specified element to the **end** of this list.
>
> `add(int index, E element)` –
>   Inserts the specified element at the **specified index** in this
>   list.

You can add multiple elements with `addAll`.

Answer (score 1):

`new ArrayList(SIZE)` will not limit your list to `SIZE` element, but will just initialize its inner array responsible for storing elements to length equal to `SIZE`. But it doesn't mean that later this list will not be able to store more than `SIZE` elements, because it still can later create new larger array with old elements and use it internally.

In other words returned list is still resizeable. It is also *empty* at start (its `size()` is 0) so there is no reason for `add` to start adding elements on other indexes than `0`.