# From ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> to fixed size array/list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have this:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> models;
```

and in the constructor I have:

```
models = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Later, I do things like:

```
models.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

as well as other operations.

I want to make the external ArrayList to something with a fixed size (Array, List) and I am really lost to how I am going to write the declaration, initialization, addition, etc. because of the nested objects. Can someone save me time by answering this for me?

Comment: Do you mean limit its size? Because if it's fixed-size, `models.add` would fail.

Comment: ArrayList is not fixed in size, arrays are. what do you mean?

Comment: Yeah something like: Array<ArrayList<Object>> models. I now the exact size of the outer "layer"

Comment: `ArrayList<Object> [] array`?

Comment: @JohnZobolas you can create a `List` meeting whatever requirements you need by extending [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207162/define-a-fixed-size-list-in-java

Comment: @AndyTurner - You're correct. I deleted the comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.asList()` to created fixed sized `List`s.

Examples:

A `List` of size 3, initialized with null values:

```
List<ArrayList<Object>> models = Arrays.asList (null,null,null);
```

A `List` of size 3, initialized with non-null values:

```
List<ArrayList<Object>> models = Arrays.asList (new ArrayList<Object> (),new ArrayList<Object> (),new ArrayList<Object> ());
```

A `List` of size 10, initialized with null values:

```
List<ArrayList<Object>> models = Arrays.asList ((ArrayList<Object>[])new ArrayList[10]);
```

Note that `add` operation is not supported for fixed sized lists. You'll have to use `models.set(index,new ArrayList<Object>())` instead.

EDIT:

Here's another way to initialize the `List` using `Stream`s:

```
List<ArrayList<Object>> models = Arrays.asList (Stream.generate (ArrayList::new).limit (10).toArray (ArrayList[]::new));
```

Comment: Once you get the list from list, you won't be able to modify it.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You can replace the elements (the same way you can replace elements in arrays), you just can't add or remove elements.

Comment: `you just can't add or remove elements.` yeah. That is what I am trying to say :(

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ which is exactly what the OP requested - `I want to make the external ArrayList to something with a **fixed size**`

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ That's was the OP was looking for.

Comment: May be I am wrong. What I have understood is, He wants to declares list with some size X and then nobody else can add more than X size.

Comment: @Eran Is there any reason to use Varargs as opposed to Arrays.asList(new Object[size])

Comment: @Eran what I don't like about this, that once exposed all the user of this sees is a `List` - it has no idea that it's immutable. I would suggest to just declare it to be immutable - unfortunately only with a help of some external lib, like guava, `ImmutableList<...>`

Comment: @Eran, can you please add code for when I have a fixed size of 10, to add it as: Arrays.asList (10 X new ArrayList<Object> () )?

Comment: @Zachary you can do something similar to what you suggested. I edited the answer.

Comment: I get this when I am creating initializing: "Type safety: Unchecked cast from ArrayList[] to ArrayList<Object>[]". Is it OK?

Comment: @JohnZobolas There's no way to avoid that, since you can't instantiate generic arrays.

Comment: @Eugene But the requirement is not for an ImmutableList. A fixed sized list is a different thing.

Comment: @JohnZobolas Please see my latest edit. When using a `Stream` to generate the array, I don't get a warning and I don't need the cast.

Comment: @Eran I will see it, thanks! So, I cannot add, remove, etc to the list, but to the `ArrayList<Object>` inside I can do it, correct? Like: `models.get(index).add(model)`; where model is `ArrayList<Object>`

Comment: @JohnZobolas Yes, you can only add/remove elements to/from the inner ArrayLists. Are you saying that the inner ArrayLists also contain ArrayLists? That's a complex structure.

Comment: @Eran, no more ArrayLists inside :) just objects of a generic type of a model I am using. Testing this now, later I will mark it as best answer!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more verbose - but generic-compatible way - of doing it is to extend [`AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

The methods you need to override are described in the Javadoc:

> To implement an unmodifiable list, the programmer needs only to extend this class and provide implementations for the `get(int)` and `size()`methods.
>
> To implement a modifiable list, the programmer must additionally override the `set(int, E)` method (which otherwise throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`).

So, implement these three methods, delegating to an `ArrayList`:

```
class FixedSizedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
  private final List<T> delegate;

  FixedSizedList(int size) {
    delegate = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(size, null));
  }

  public T get(int i) { return delegate.get(i); }
  public int size() { return delegate.size(); }
  public T set(int i, T e) { return delegate.set(i, e); }
}
```

Or, for that matter, just use an array:

```
class FixedSizedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
  private final Object[] array;

  FixedSizedList(int size) {
    array = new Object[size];
  }

  public T get(int i) { return (T) array[i]; }
  public int size() { return array.length; }
  public T set(int i, T e) {
    T old = (T) array[i];
    array[i] = e;
    return old;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Eugene no, it doesn't. That's the thing about extending `AbstractList`: it does the right thing for all the methods it doesn't ask you to override.

Comment: @Eugene when can you ever add elements by throwing an exception?

Comment: @Eugene it's a fixed-sized list: it never holds zero elements, unless you construct it to have zero elements. If you construct it with 10 elements, it stores 10 null elements initially.

Comment: oh my! I completly missed the `Collections.nCopies(size, null)` inside the constructor. :| will remove the comments

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an `Array` class in java, but there is the plain old array declaration:

```
ArrayList<Object> [] array...
```

Problem is that you will not be able to instantiate it like this, since arrays can not be generic.

You are really looking for either `Arrays.asList` or much better `ImmutableList` of some kind.