# Fixed-size List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

How to create instances of List with fixed sizes (it is not possible to perform add() operations on them, but it is possible to perform set())? When I try to change `fields.set(i, board.get(i).get(x));` into `fields.add(new SudokuField());` I do not get compiler errors in IntelliJ.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SudokuBoard {

    private final List<List<SudokuField>> board = new ArrayList<>();
    private final SudokuSolver solver;
    //private final List<ComponentObserver> observers = Arrays.asList(new ComponentObserver[3]);
    private final ComponentObserver[] observers = new ComponentObserver[3];
    private boolean state = true;

    public SudokuBoard(SudokuSolver solver) {
        this.solver = Objects.requireNonNull(solver);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            List<SudokuField> row = Arrays.asList(new SudokuField[9]);
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                row.set(j, new SudokuField());
            }
            board.add(row);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            observers[i] = new ComponentObserver();
        }
    }

    public void solveGame() {
        solver.solve(this);
    }

    public boolean isSafe() {
        return checkBoard();
    }

    public int get(int y, int x) {
        return board.get(y).get(x).getFieldValue();
    }

    private  void setState() {
        state = observers[0].getCorrectState();
        state &= observers[1].getCorrectState();
        state &= observers[2].getCorrectState();
    }

    private void update(int y, int x) {
        observers[0].update(getRow(y));
        observers[1].update(getColumn(x));
        observers[2].update(getBox(y, x));
    }

    public void set(int y, int x, int value) {
        board.get(y).get(x).setFieldValue(value);
        update(y, x);
        setState();
    }

    public SudokuRow getRow(int y) {
        List<SudokuField> fields = Arrays.asList(new SudokuField[9]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            fields.set(i, board.get(y).get(i));
        }
        return new SudokuRow(fields);
    }

    public SudokuColumn getColumn(int x) {
        List<SudokuField> fields = Arrays.asList(new SudokuField[9]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            fields.set(i, board.get(i).get(x));
        }
        return new SudokuColumn(fields);
    }

    public SudokuBox getBox(int y, int x) {
        List<SudokuField> fields = Arrays.asList(new SudokuField[9]);
        int row = y / 3 * 3;
        int col = x / 3 * 3;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = row; i < row + 3; i++) {
            for (int j = col; j < col + 3; j++) {
                fields.set(index, board.get(i).get(j));
                index++;
            }
        }
        return new SudokuBox(fields);
    }

    private boolean checkBoard() {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define a fixed-size list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207162/define-a-fixed-size-list-in-java)

Comment: The `List` interface has an `add` method, you will not get a compile-time error whatever you do. You may get an `UnsupportedOperationException` at runtime if you choose an implementation of `List` that left the method unimplemented.

Comment: I think you're using the right code to create fixed size List. Maybe the issue is coming from the content you're trying to add into the List ? I suppose it can be null when you call : board.get[...].get[...]

Comment: This is a great exercise, slightly more challenging than most.

Answer (score 3):

I think you dont need `java.util.List`. You can just use normal arrays!

```java
public class Test {
    SudokuField[][] board = new int[size_1][size_2];
    
    public void get() {
        System.out.println(board[x][y]);
    }
    public void set() {
        board[x][y] = value;
    }
}
```

---

Or if you REALY need List you can do something like this:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Object> board = new ArrayList<>(){
            @Override
            public boolean add(Object o) {
                if (super.size() + 1 >= YOUR_SIZE) {
                    return false; 
                }
                return super.add(o);
            }

            @Override
            public void add(int index, Object element) {
                if (super.size() + 1 >= YOUR_SIZE) {
                    return false;
                }
                super.add(index, element);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And it actually is in apchare commons library.

> The Apache Commons library provides the FixedSizeList class which does not support the add, remove and clear methods (but the set method is allowed because it does not modify the List's size). Ditto for FixedSizeList in Eclipse Collections. If you try to call one of these methods, your list remains the same size.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968535/22257686

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How to create instances of List with fixed sizes ..."*

I don't believe there is anything within the *Java Framework*.

Here is the *JavaDoc* for the *Collections Framework*.
*[The Collections Framework (Java SE 21 & JDK 21)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/doc-files/coll-index.html#the-collections-framework-heading)*.

Similar to *@Denis*'s answer, just use an *array*, which are of a fixed-length, by default.
*[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)*.

```java
SudokuField[][] board = new SudokuField[9][9];
```

Alternately, encapsulate the *ArrayList* class, checking the parameters for each *"add"* method.

Here is an example.

```java
class SudokuFieldList extends ArrayList<List<SudokuField>> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(List<SudokuField> e) {
        if (size() == 9 || e.size() > 9)
            throw new ListOutOfBoundsException();
        return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, List<SudokuField> element) {
        if (size() == 9 || index >= 9 || element.size() > 9)
            throw new ListOutOfBoundsException();
        super.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends List<SudokuField>> c) {
        if (size() == 9 || c.size() > 9)
            throw new ListOutOfBoundsException();
        return super.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends List<SudokuField>> c) {
        if (size() == 9 || index >= 9 || c.size() > 9)
            throw new ListOutOfBoundsException();
        return super.addAll(index, c);
    }

    static class ListOutOfBoundsException extends RuntimeException { }
}
```

And, here is an example usage; intentionally erroring.

```java
SudokuFieldList l = new SudokuFieldList();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) l.add(List.of());
```

```
Exception in thread "main" Example$SudokuFieldList$ListOutOfBoundsException
    at Example$SudokuFieldList.add(Example.java:17)
    at Example.main(Example.java:10)
```

On a final note, here is a *Wikipedia* article on solving *Sudoku* puzzles.
*[Wikipedia – Sudoku solving algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms#Sudoku_brute_force)*.