# Java collection keeping only n last inserted members

Tags: java, collections

As the title states, I am looking for a java collection keeping only the N last objects inserted into the collection. This FIFO collection does not need to implement random access or support changing N.

All collections I can find are either blocking ([LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)) or of unlimited size ([ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)). I found org.eclipse.jetty.util.ArrayQueue but as you could guess this brings quite an unwanted dependency on my project and also is very complicated since it support changing N so its not what I need.

Do you know if there is a way to have that with a quite common java library or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer

Comment: What do you want to happen to the 'expired' elements?

Comment: See the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422181/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-entries-in-a-java-hashtable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size-limited queue that holds last N elements in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [Apache Commons CircularFifoBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html)

> CircularFifoBuffer is a first in first out buffer with a fixed size
>   that replaces its oldest element if full.
>
> The removal order of a CircularFifoBuffer is based on the insertion
>   order; elements are removed in the same order in which they were
>   added. The iteration order is the same as the removal order.

Comment: Hmmm -- that looks like it won't let you add elements when it's full, though, which isn't what OP wants.

Comment: @SamMussmann - Whoops. Was thinking of the CircularFifoBuffer. Now corrected

Comment: See CircularFifoQueue for a generic solution

Answer (score 2):

I would just write a wrapper class which contains a private Queue or Deque instance and a public insert method which behaves as you need if the queue is already full when the client tries to insert an extra member. The size could be passed in via the constructor, and any methods belonging to Queue or Deque which you need available but which already behave as you need you could simply forward to the private instance.

Answer (score 2):

After Guava 15.0 there's EvictingQueue which come with a fixed size that replaces its oldest element if full.