# Is there an equivalent of the python function id() in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

I am looking for a matlab function that has the same functionality as python's `id()`, i.e. something unique for an object, and constant through its lifetime..

Comment: what kind of matlab's object do you need an `id()` for?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/3314 might help

Comment: @dfb: Thanks, I'm checking it out.

Comment: why do you need this functionality for? you can compare matlab arrays using `isequal`

Comment: @Shai:I need to perform some sort of caching.

Comment: please provide a borader context so we can provide better answers.

Comment: @Shai:
I am transcribing code for a machine learning algorithm (BAHSIC) from python 2.6 into Matlab (R2008a). There is a bunch of Kernels that needs to be implemented, and requires pre-processing the input data and then caching it as a part of the kernel object. The way it has been done in python is cache[id(x)] = (x**2).sum(axis=1).
The variable cache here is a part of the kernel object.
I need to do the same in matlab.

Comment: @ktulsyan: [Caching result of pre-computed function in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178367/caching-result-of-pre-computed-function-in-matlab) (also see the links provided in there)

Comment: you could also use the undocumented [`mxSerialize`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6261884/97160) to serialize any variable in MATLAB and generate a hash from the byte stream

Comment: Another alternative is to create your own struct consisting of a unique ID and the data, though this might be tedious to implement

Answer (score 3):

For all handle-like objects the identifier analogue to id() is probably the double-converted value:

```
>> h = uicontrol
h =
  9.7656e-004
>> handle(h)
ans =
    uicontrol
```

For non-handle type objects such a thing probably doesn't exists, since Matlab usually uses call-by-value instead of call-by-reference.
So in general, upon changing a variable's value, there's no guarantee that the underlying object remains the same.