# Dictionary or similar data structure that only stores the most recent n entries?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I'm wondering if there's a built-in Java data structure that behaves like a dictionary *but* only keeps a fixed number of recent entries. So I could keep the size more-or-less constant but also have it behave like a dictionary or hashmap.

Comment: So you want a keyed cache, managed on something like an LRU replacement basis.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/224886/702638

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy, simple to use LRU cache in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224868/easy-simple-to-use-lru-cache-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You could create one quite easily by extending LinkedHashMap. When adding an entry, check the size and remove the oldest item if already at maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

I think [LRUMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap.html) will suit your need.