# Object cache data structure with "object expiration"

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, collections

Which data structure in Java would be best to implement an in-memory object cache, where objects have an individual expiration time?

Basically for the cache I could use a Map (where key could be a String) which offers the put and get methods, and use a ordered list of "timestamp"+"object" pairs to manage the expiration time. So a cleanup thread could check the first list entry and delete the object when its expiration time passed. (Deletion of the first element should be in O(1) time)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're describing building is basically my [ExpiringMap](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap). There are other similar implementations, such as Guava (see [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html)) - though I don't believe it supports per-entry expiration as ExpiringMap does.

Comment: +1 for Guava`s CacheBuilder. I consider it the most appropriate suggestion as it is easy to use and lightweight.

Comment: Upvoted because the OP is not asking for a farm of cache servers, but for an in-memory cache structure. Guava `Cache` is the best fit here.

Comment: how can one set expiration per object with guava?

Comment: @sodik I don't think Guava supports per-entry expiration. [ExpiringMap](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap) does though. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 6):

Caching frameworks are pretty mature now:

- EhCache: http://ehcache.org/
- Memcached: http://memcached.org/

However, if you insist on reinventing the wheel, remember to account for memory utilisation. All too often I see a badly implemented cache (`HashMap`) effectively turn into a memory leak.

See Cowan's answer here: [Java's WeakHashMap and caching: Why is it referencing the keys, not the values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802809/javas-weakhashmap-and-caching-why-is-it-referencing-the-keys-not-the-values)

Answer (score 4):

I would consider using an existing library like `ehcache`.

However, if you want to write your own, I would not use a background thread unless you need it as it adds complexity. Instead I would have the foreground thread remove expired entries.

I would use `LinkedHashMap` if you just need an LRU cache. However if you want timed expiry, I would use a `HashMap` with a `PriorityQueue` (so you can check whether the next to expire entry has expired)

Comment: Indeed, `LinkedHashMap` is an excellent choice. But one thing to clarify: to achive removal of the expired entries you would combine `LinkedHashMap` with some thread that does this job, correct? If yes, don't you think that it will slightly decrease performance of such cache? And secondly: why foreground thread instead of background?

Comment: @GrzesiekD. You can remove expired items when you access the map instead of using background thread.

Answer (score 4):

Guava Cachebuilder :

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(10000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

Since WeekHashmap doesn't fit caching but you can always utilize `Map<K,WeakReference<V>>` whose value become eligible for GC for week references.

Above all we always have **EhCache** ,**Memcached** and **coherence**  as popular choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think your decision is right.
I would be using HashMap to be exact.

Comment: Poor choice, `LinkedHashMap` would be much better here, as it has the ability to reduce memory consumption by deleting stale entries.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous answers, it is better to use one of the popular in-memory caches like EhCache, Memcached etc.

But just as you wanted implement it by your own cache which has the object expiry feature and less time complexity, I tried to implement it like this - (any test reviews/suggestions much appreciated)..

```
public class ObjectCache<K, V> {

    private volatile boolean shutdown;
    private final long maxObjects;
    private final long timeToLive;
    private final long removalThreadRunDelay;
    private final long objectsToRemovePerRemovalThreadRun;
    private final AtomicLong objectsCount;
    private final Map<K, CacheEntryWrapper> cachedDataStore;
    private final BlockingQueue<CacheEntryReference> queue;
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

    public ObjectCache(long maxObjects, long timeToLive, long removalThreadRunDelay, long objectsToRemovePerRemovalThreadRun) {
        this.maxObjects = maxObjects;
        this.timeToLive = timeToLive;
        this.removalThreadRunDelay = removalThreadRunDelay;
        this.objectsToRemovePerRemovalThreadRun = objectsToRemovePerRemovalThreadRun;
        this.objectsCount = new AtomicLong(0);
        this.cachedDataStore = new HashMap<K, CacheEntryWrapper>();
        this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<CacheEntryReference>();
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key and Value both should be not null");
        }
        if (objectsCount.get() + 1 > maxObjects) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Max objects limit reached. Can not store more objects in cache.");
        }
        // create a value wrapper and add it to data store map
        CacheEntryWrapper entryWrapper = new CacheEntryWrapper(key, value);
        synchronized (lock) {
            cachedDataStore.put(key, entryWrapper);
        }
        // add the cache entry reference to queue which will be used by removal thread
        queue.add(entryWrapper.getCacheEntryReference());
        objectsCount.incrementAndGet();
        // start the removal thread if not started already
        if (executorService == null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (executorService == null) {
                    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                    executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new CacheEntryRemover(), 0, removalThreadRunDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key can not be null");
        }
        CacheEntryWrapper entryWrapper;
        synchronized (lock) {
            entryWrapper = cachedDataStore.get(key);
            if (entryWrapper != null) {
                // reset the last access time
                entryWrapper.resetLastAccessedTime();
                // reset the reference (so the weak reference is cleared)
                entryWrapper.resetCacheEntryReference();
                // add the new reference to queue
                queue.add(entryWrapper.getCacheEntryReference());
            }
        }
        return entryWrapper == null ? null : entryWrapper.getValue();
    }

    public void remove(K key) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key can not be null");
        }
        CacheEntryWrapper entryWrapper;
        synchronized (lock) {
            entryWrapper = cachedDataStore.remove(key);
            if (entryWrapper != null) {
                // reset the reference (so the weak reference is cleared)
                entryWrapper.resetCacheEntryReference();
            }
        }
        objectsCount.decrementAndGet();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        shutdown = true;
        executorService.shutdown();
        queue.clear();
        cachedDataStore.clear();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectCache<Long, Long> cache = new ObjectCache<>(1000000, 60000, 1000, 1000);
        long i = 0;
        while (i++ < 10000) {
            cache.put(i, i);
        }
        i = 0;
        while(i++ < 100) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Data store size: " + cache.cachedDataStore.size() + ", queue size: " + cache.queue.size());
        }
        cache.shutdown();
    }

    private class CacheEntryRemover implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            if (!shutdown) {
                try {
                    int count = 0;
                    CacheEntryReference entryReference;
                    while ((entryReference = queue.peek()) != null && count++ < objectsToRemovePerRemovalThreadRun) {
                        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        CacheEntryWrapper cacheEntryWrapper = entryReference.getWeakReference().get();
                        if (cacheEntryWrapper == null || !cachedDataStore.containsKey(cacheEntryWrapper.getKey())) {
                            queue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // remove the reference object from queue as value is removed from cache
                        } else if (currentTime - cacheEntryWrapper.getLastAccessedTime().get() > timeToLive) {
                            synchronized (lock) {
                                // get the cacheEntryWrapper again just to find if put() has overridden the same key or remove() has removed it already
                                CacheEntryWrapper newCacheEntryWrapper = cachedDataStore.get(cacheEntryWrapper.getKey());
                                // poll the queue if -
                                // case 1 - value is removed from cache
                                // case 2 - value is overridden by new value
                                // case 3 - value is still in cache but it is old now
                                if (newCacheEntryWrapper == null || newCacheEntryWrapper != cacheEntryWrapper || currentTime - cacheEntryWrapper.getLastAccessedTime().get() > timeToLive) {
                                    queue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                                    newCacheEntryWrapper = newCacheEntryWrapper == null ? cacheEntryWrapper : newCacheEntryWrapper;
                                    if (currentTime - newCacheEntryWrapper.getLastAccessedTime().get() > timeToLive) {
                                        remove(newCacheEntryWrapper.getKey());
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    break; // try next time
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class CacheEntryWrapper {
        private K key;
        private V value;
        private AtomicLong lastAccessedTime;
        private CacheEntryReference cacheEntryReference;

        public CacheEntryWrapper(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.lastAccessedTime = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
            this.cacheEntryReference = new CacheEntryReference(this);
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public AtomicLong getLastAccessedTime() {
            return lastAccessedTime;
        }

        public CacheEntryReference getCacheEntryReference() {
            return cacheEntryReference;
        }

        public void resetLastAccessedTime() {
            lastAccessedTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        public void resetCacheEntryReference() {
            cacheEntryReference.clear();
            cacheEntryReference = new CacheEntryReference(this);
        }
    }

    private class CacheEntryReference {
        private WeakReference<CacheEntryWrapper> weakReference;

        public CacheEntryReference(CacheEntryWrapper entryWrapper) {
            this.weakReference = new WeakReference<CacheEntryWrapper>(entryWrapper);
        }

        public WeakReference<CacheEntryWrapper> getWeakReference() {
            return weakReference;
        }

        public void clear() {
            weakReference.clear();
        }
    }
}
```