# How to specify the right type for ReferenceQueue.remove() in Java?

Tags: java, weak-references

I have a class with a `ReferenceQueue` of `WeakReference`s.

```
class Example<K,V>
{
    ReferenceQueue<WeakReference<V>> queue = null;
    Thread cleanup = null;
[...]
    Example () {
        queue = new ReferenceQueue<WeakReference<V>>();
        cleanup = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for (;;) {
                            WeakReference<V> ref = queue.remove();
[...]
```

But when I try to compile this I get an "incompatible types" error:

```
found   : java.lang.ref.Reference<capture#189 of ? extends java.lang.ref.WeakReference<V>>
required: java.lang.ref.WeakReference<V>
                            WeakReference<V> ref = queue.remove();
                                                               ^
```

I do not understand this, because I have defined the reference queue as a queue of weak references of V and so I expect a weak reference of V as a result of `remove()`.

Is this wrong? How can I fix this?

I tried also `Reference<V>` as a return value of `remove()` but that does not help. I tried the cast the result but that turns the error only into a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `ReferenceQueue<V>`, not `ReferenceQueue<WeakReference<V>>`.  You'll need to explicitly cast the references you pull out of the queue to `WeakReference<V>`.

Comment: Is there no way to get the type right without generating the "unchecked cast" warning?

Comment: Ok. I added a `@SuppressWarnings`. My [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802809/javas-weakhashmap-and-caching-why-is-it-referencing-the-keys-not-the-values/16991188#16991188) seems to work.