# How to "attach" to an Object

Tags: java

Assume here is a `Button` object which I cannot modify, and I want to add some function to it, making it draggable for example, so I create a class `Draggable` as follows:

```
public class Draggable {

    private Button button;

    private Draggable(Button button) {this.button = button;}

    // attach to a button
    public static Draggable attachTo(Button button) {
        return new Draggable(button);
    }

    // retrieve Draggable object attached to the button
    public static Draggable of(Button button) {
        // ...
    }

    // detatch from button
    public static void detachFrom(Button button) {
        Draggable d = of(button);
        if (d != null) {d.button = null;}
    }
}
```

Whenever the `Button` object is destroyed and garbage collected, the `Draggable` object attached to it should also be garbage collectable automatically. So is there a design pattern or something that can help me implement this `of()` method?

Comment: Answer to your quesiton is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506488/when-is-the-finalize-method-called-in-java

Comment: Have you considered inheritance?

Comment: @Sweeper these objects are provided by others, so creating a sub class for every one of these types would be inextensible.

Comment: @GhostCat The first further reading link is fully helpful that I have solved the problem with WeakHashMap. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need an internal cache based on [WeakReferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

In other words: your `Draggalbe` can only be subject to garbage collection when **no** "hard" alive reference is pointing to it.

In other words:

- every time you create a `Draggabe` you put that into your cache
- you periodically check the cache if the weak references cached in there are still valid
- when you find a weak reference that turned `null` - you delete the entry from the cache

And of course - you have to make sure that *no* other "life" object keeps a hard reference to a `Draggable` object.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802809/javas-weakhashmap-and-caching-why-is-it-referencing-the-keys-not-the-values) and [there](http://www.programmr.com/blogs/what-every-java-developer-should-know-strong-and-weak-references) for further reading.