# scala type woes: SoftReference, ReferenceQueues, SoftHashMap

Tags: scala, types, reference

**EDIT** *Most answers thus far are focusing on the fact that I was incorrectly extending Map. I have corrected this in the example code, but the type woes persist, and the question still stands.*

I'm trying to implement a `SoftHashMap` in Scala, but am running into a type mismatch error:

```
inferred type arguments [K,V] do not conform to class SoftValue's type parameter bounds [K,+V <: AnyRef]
val sv = new SoftValue(kv._1, kv._2, queue)
```

I understand that I'm over-constraining the types, but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map, HashMap}    
import scala.ref._

class SoftValue[K, +V <: AnyRef](val key:K, value:V, queue:ReferenceQueue[V]) extends SoftReference(value, queue)

class SoftMap[K, V] extends Map[K, V]
{
  private val map = new HashMap[K, SoftValue[K, V]]

  private val queue = new ReferenceQueue[V]

  override def +=(kv: (K, V)):this.type =
  {
    val sv = new SoftValue(kv._1, kv._2, queue)
    map(kv._1) = sv
    this
  }
}
```

Comment: First things first. Are you extending scala.collection.mutable.Map? In any case, '+' in Map returns a new instance of Map ("Creates a new map containing a new key/value mapping and all the key/value mappings of this map").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compiles. (edit: I initially added `val value` but that created a strong reference). Not sure how you want to handle iterator...

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map, HashMap}    
import scala.ref._

class SoftValue[K, +V <: AnyRef](val key:K, value:V, 
  queue:ReferenceQueue[V]) extends SoftReference(value, queue)

class SoftMap[K, V <: AnyRef] extends Map[K, V] {
  private val map = new HashMap[K, SoftValue[K, V]]
  private val queue = new ReferenceQueue[V]

  def +=(kv: (K, V)): this.type = {
    val sv = new SoftValue(kv._1, kv._2, queue)
    map(kv._1) = sv
    this
  }

  def -=(k: K): this.type = { map -= k; this }
  def get(k: K) = map.get(k).flatMap(_.get)
  def iterator: Iterator[(K,V)] = error("todo")
}
```

You're missing `V <: AnyRef` when defining `SoftMap`, so that *V* can be used as argument of the `SoftValue` *constructor*.

Comment: To see a full implementation check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112219/is-there-a-softhashmap-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

First problem, as pointed out by Sam, is that you are extending `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, which you are accessing through the alias `scala.Map`.

Second, you have declared `V` as a covariant type parameter. This would mean that a `SoftMap[String, Dog]` is a subtype of `SoftMap[String, Any]`. It is not valid to refer to the covariant type parameter in a contravariant position in the class definition.

```
trait Contra[+A] {
    def a: A    // method return type is a covariant position, okay
    def m(a: A) // method parameter is a contravariant position, error
    def n[AA >: A](a: AA) // upper bound of a type param is in covariant position, okay
}
```

Typesafe mutable collections need to refer to the element type in both co- and contravariant positions: to retrieve elements and to add elements respectively. For this reason, they must declare the type parameter as invariant.

The definition of `collection.mutable.Map` shows this:

```
trait Map[A, B] 
  extends Iterable[(A, B)]
     with scala.collection.Map[A, B] 
     with MapLike[A, B, Map[A, B]]
```

If you extend this, you will be told:

```
scala> trait SoftMap[K, +V] extends collection.mutable.Map[K, V]
<console>:25: error: covariant type V occurs in invariant position in type [K,+V]java.lang.Object with scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,V] of trait SoftMap
       trait SoftMap[K, +V] extends collection.mutable.Map[K, V]
             ^
```

On the other hand:

```
scala> trait SoftMap[K, V] extends collection.mutable.Map[K, V]
defined trait SoftMap
```

The final issue, also pointed out by Sam, is that the method `+` doesn't [do what you intend](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src///library/scala/collection/mutable/MapLike.scala#L90), at least since Scala 2.8. You should implement [the method `+=`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src///library/scala/collection/mutable/MapLike.scala#L64).

Answer (score 1):

If `SoftMap` is going to be mutable, then you cannot update it with a supertype `V1` of it's value type `V`. If that were possible, the old map would have a binding to a key-value pair with a value of type `V1`, and the type of the old map is `V`. This would result in type errors when looking up the new binding in the old map.

Mutable maps implement `+` by copying the map, immutable maps have a more efficient `+`. On the other hand, mutable maps have `+=` which modifies the existing map and is more efficient. The argument of `+=` is a key and a value, where a value isn't the supertype of the map value type.

In this case, the solution is to copy the map.

EDIT:

The error message you've got after changing the question above is due to the fact that the type parameter `V` of the soft map can be any type whatsoever, while the type `V` of the `SoftValue` has to be a subtype of `AnyRef` (cannot be an `Int` or a `Float`, that is, a subtype of `AnyVal`). Therefore, you cannot create a `SoftValue` with the type `V` from the `SoftMap`, because someone might instantiate the `SoftMap` by setting the `V` to, say `Int`.