# Best way to implement LRU cache

Tags: java, c++, caching

I was looking at this problem of LRU cache implementation where after the size of the cache is full, the least recently used item is popped out and it is replaced by the new item.

I have two implementations in mind:

1). Create two maps which looks something like this

```
std::map<timestamp, k> time_to_key
std::map<key, std::pair<timestamp, V>> LRUCache
```

To insert a new element, we can put the current timestamp and value in the *LRUCache*. While when the size of the cache is full, we can evict the least recent element by finding the smallest timestamp present in *time*_to_*key* and removing the corresponding key from *LRUCache*.
Inserting a new item is O(1), updating the timestamp is O(n) (because we need to search the *k* corresponding to the timestamp in *time*_to_*key*.

2). Have a linked list in which the least recently used cache is present at the head and the new item is added at the tail. When an item arrives which is already present in the cache, the node corresponding to the key of that item is moved to the tail of the list. 
Inserting a new item is O(1), updating the timestamp is again O(n) (because we need to move to the tail of the list), and deleting an element is O(1).

Now I have the following questions:

1. Which one of these implementations is better for an LRUCache.
2. Is there any other way to implement the LRU Cache.
3. In Java, should I use HashMap to implement the LRUCache
4. I have seen questions like, implement a generic LRU cache, and also have seen questions like implementing an LRU cache. Is generic LRU cache different from LRU cache?

Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT:**

Another way (easiest way) to implement LRUCache in Java is by using LinkedHashMap and by overriding the boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.entry eldest) function.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221525/how-would-you-implement-an-lru-cache-in-java-6

Comment: in java you should use LinkedHashMap and close to never HashMap. Best LRU maps use some form of Map w/ linked nodes, i.e. it can be implemented with binary search red-black and linked (prev/next) nodes aside parent/left/right/value/red|black fields. Or what LinkedHashMap is: tree based buckets w/ prev/next.

Comment: HashMap, HashTable, LinkedHashMap in Java are implemented using hashtables i.e. array and linear probing for collision resolution. They are not implemented as red black trees

Comment: I never told they are red-black, you can see TreeMap, adding prev/next to the nodes is not hard, I have a similar map for primitive doubles, i.e. red-black w/ prev/next between the nodes.

Comment: yup adding prev/next in a tree data structure is not hard, but i wonder wont u need to modify the internal TreeMap class if u want to add prev/next node?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want an LRU cache, the simplest in Java is LinkedHashMap. The default behaviour is FIFO however you can changes it to "access order" which makes it an LRU cache.

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> lruCache(final int maxSize) {
    return new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(maxSize*4/3, 0.75f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
            return size() > maxSize;
        }
    };
}
```

Note: I have using the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap-int-float-boolean-) which changes the collection from newest first to most recently used first.

From the Javadoc

```
public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity,
                     float loadFactor,
                     boolean accessOrder)
Constructs an empty LinkedHashMap instance with the specified initial capacity, load factor and ordering mode.
Parameters:
initialCapacity - the initial capacity
loadFactor - the load factor
accessOrder - the ordering mode - true for access-order, false for insertion-order
```

When accessOrder is `true` the LinkedHashMap re-arranges the order of the map whenever you get() an entry which is not the last one.

This way the oldest entry is the least which is recently used.

Comment: your code will remove eldest entry and not least recently used.  eldest entry could be most recently used entry also.

Comment: @AmrishPandey when you use change the ordering mode to "access order"  it becomes and LRU cache. (See my updated answer)

Comment: Excellent !!!  Didn't know we can change order to access order.  Tested this, works fine. Most of the implementations use combination of hashmap and DLL

Comment: Why did you use cacheSize as (4/3 * cacheSize) instead of cacheSize   and also the load factor as 0.75f, what is the need of giving a load factor when our HashMap won't exceed  the initial cacheSize(we have to iterate n pages over our fixed HashMap).

Comment: @NikhilVerma The default load factor is 0.75 and making it higher can be inefficient. With a load factor of 0.75 you need a capacity of `cacheSize/0.75` or `cacheSize*4/3` otherwise the Map might resize to ensure it stays below it's load factor. i.e. capacity * loadFactor >= size().

Comment: But the HashMap doesn't need to resized ?, as we change the elements in the original array of size (ex.4) ?

Comment: @NikhilVerma it doesn't need to resize if you make the capacity large enough. If you make it too small e.g. the number of elements you add, it will resize.

Comment: @NikhilVerma it resizes when the size > capacity * 0.75 so it you want to avoid resizing the capacity >= size / 0.75

Comment: @PeterLawrey :  I want to ask what is the simplest & efficient way of implementing thread-safe LRU cache ? Using read-write lock with HashMap/Doubly LinkedList ?

Comment: @SahilGupta I would still use a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: In Clojure:

```
(let [size (/ (* max-size 4) 3) p (proxy [java.util.LinkedHashMap] [size,0.75,true] (removeEldestEntry [e] (> (proxy-super size) size)))] ...)
```

Comment: @johanatan you want the capacity to be 4/3* larger but the size check to be max-size. Interesting code though.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, LRU caches are represented as LIFO structures- a single queue of elements. If the one provided by your Standard doesn't allow you to remove objects from the middle, for example, to put them on the top, then you may have to roll your own.

Comment: Can the time complexity of updating the timestamp be improved from O(n) to constant?

Comment: yes, it can be O(1), see my comment above, LinkedHashMap in java is O(1)

Comment: LinkedHashMap provides a way to iterate through the keys present in the map, but finding the least recent key/value pair will again require sequential search

Comment: @Amm, the first (to be removed) is O(1). map.entrySet().iterator().next() or you can override `removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest)`, LinkedHashMap doesn't provide tail (i.e the last added/touched) and reverse traverse although it's practically supported by the structure.

Comment: If the item to be removed is somewhere in the middle in the list, then wont u need to reach to that element in order to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the cache allows concurrent access, the problem of good design of LRU cache boils down to:

a) Can we avoid using mutex while updating the two structures(cache structure and LRU structure).

b) Will the read (get) operation of cache require mutex?

In more detail: Say, if we implements this using java.util.concurrent.ConcuurentHashMap(cache structure) and java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue(LRU structure)

a)Locking both these two structures on edit operations - addEntry(), removeEntry(), evictEntries() etc.

b) The above could probably pass as slow write operations, but the problem is even for read (get) operation, we need to apply lock on both the structures. Because, get will mean putting the entry in front of the queue for LRU strategy.(Assuming entries are removed from end of the queue).

Using efficient concurrent structures like ConcurrentHashMap and wait free ConcurrentLinkedQueue and then putting a lock over them is loosing the whole purpose of it.

I implemented an LRU cache with the same approach, however, the LRU structured was updated asynchronously eliminating the need of using any mutex while accessing these structures. LRU is an internal detail of the Cache and can be implemented in any manner without affecting the users of the cache.

Later, I also read about ConcurrentLinkedHashMap

https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/

And found that it is also trying to do the same thing. Not used this structure but perhaps might be a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand on some of these suggestions with two possible implementations. One not thread safe, and one that might be.

Here is a simplest version with a unit test that shows it works.

First the non-concurrent version:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LruSimpleCache<K, V> implements LruCache <K, V>{

    Map<K, V> map = new LinkedHashMap (  );


    public LruSimpleCache (final int limit) {
           map = new LinkedHashMap <K, V> (16, 0.75f, true) {
               @Override
               protected boolean removeEldestEntry(final Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
                   return super.size() > limit;
               }
           };
    }
    @Override
    public void put ( K key, V value ) {
        map.put ( key, value );
    }

    @Override
    public V get ( K key ) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    //For testing only
    @Override
    public V getSilent ( K key ) {
        V value =  map.get ( key );
        if (value!=null) {
            map.remove ( key );
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove ( K key ) {
        map.remove ( key );
    }

    @Override
    public int size () {
        return map.size ();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return map.toString ();
    }


}
```

The true flag will track the access of gets and puts. See JavaDocs. The removeEdelstEntry without the true flag to the constructor would just implement a FIFO cache (see notes below on FIFO and removeEldestEntry).

Here is the test that proves it works as an LRU cache:

```
public class LruSimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void test () {
        LruCache <Integer, Integer> cache = new LruSimpleCache<> ( 4 );


        cache.put ( 0, 0 );
        cache.put ( 1, 1 );

        cache.put ( 2, 2 );
        cache.put ( 3, 3 );


        boolean ok = cache.size () == 4 || die ( "size" + cache.size () );


        cache.put ( 4, 4 );
        cache.put ( 5, 5 );
        ok |= cache.size () == 4 || die ( "size" + cache.size () );
        ok |= cache.getSilent ( 2 ) == 2 || die ();
        ok |= cache.getSilent ( 3 ) == 3 || die ();
        ok |= cache.getSilent ( 4 ) == 4 || die ();
        ok |= cache.getSilent ( 5 ) == 5 || die ();


        cache.get ( 2 );
        cache.get ( 3 );
        cache.put ( 6, 6 );
        cache.put ( 7, 7 );
        ok |= cache.size () == 4 || die ( "size" + cache.size () );
        ok |= cache.getSilent ( 2 ) == 2 || die ();
        ok |= cache.getSilent ( 3 ) == 3 || die ();
        ok |= cache.getSilent ( 4 ) == null || die ();
        ok |= cache.getSilent ( 5 ) == null || die ();


        if ( !ok ) die ();

    }
```

Now for the concurrent version...

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class LruSimpleConcurrentCache<K, V> implements LruCache<K, V> {

    final CacheMap<K, V>[] cacheRegions;


    private static class CacheMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
        private final ReadWriteLock readWriteLock;
        private final int limit;

        CacheMap ( final int limit, boolean fair ) {
            super ( 16, 0.75f, true );
            this.limit = limit;
            readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock ( fair );

        }

        protected boolean removeEldestEntry ( final Map.Entry<K, V> eldest ) {
            return super.size () > limit;
        }


        @Override
        public V put ( K key, V value ) {
            readWriteLock.writeLock ().lock ();

            V old;
            try {

                old = super.put ( key, value );
            } finally {
                readWriteLock.writeLock ().unlock ();
            }
            return old;

        }


        @Override
        public V get ( Object key ) {
            readWriteLock.writeLock ().lock ();
            V value;

            try {

                value = super.get ( key );
            } finally {
                readWriteLock.writeLock ().unlock ();
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public V remove ( Object key ) {

            readWriteLock.writeLock ().lock ();
            V value;

            try {

                value = super.remove ( key );
            } finally {
                readWriteLock.writeLock ().unlock ();
            }
            return value;

        }

        public V getSilent ( K key ) {
            readWriteLock.writeLock ().lock ();

            V value;

            try {

                value = this.get ( key );
                if ( value != null ) {
                    this.remove ( key );
                    this.put ( key, value );
                }
            } finally {
                readWriteLock.writeLock ().unlock ();
            }
            return value;

        }

        public int size () {
            readWriteLock.readLock ().lock ();
            int size = -1;
            try {
                size = super.size ();
            } finally {
                readWriteLock.readLock ().unlock ();
            }
            return size;
        }

        public String toString () {
            readWriteLock.readLock ().lock ();
            String str;
            try {
                str = super.toString ();
            } finally {
                readWriteLock.readLock ().unlock ();
            }
            return str;
        }


    }

    public LruSimpleConcurrentCache ( final int limit, boolean fair ) {
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime ().availableProcessors ();
        int stripeSize = cores < 2 ? 4 : cores * 2;
        cacheRegions = new CacheMap[ stripeSize ];
        for ( int index = 0; index < cacheRegions.length; index++ ) {
            cacheRegions[ index ] = new CacheMap<> ( limit / cacheRegions.length, fair );
        }
    }

    public LruSimpleConcurrentCache ( final int concurrency, final int limit, boolean fair ) {

        cacheRegions = new CacheMap[ concurrency ];
        for ( int index = 0; index < cacheRegions.length; index++ ) {
            cacheRegions[ index ] = new CacheMap<> ( limit / cacheRegions.length, fair );
        }
    }

    private int stripeIndex ( K key ) {
        int hashCode = key.hashCode () * 31;
        return hashCode % ( cacheRegions.length );
    }

    private CacheMap<K, V> map ( K key ) {
        return cacheRegions[ stripeIndex ( key ) ];
    }

    @Override
    public void put ( K key, V value ) {

        map ( key ).put ( key, value );
    }

    @Override
    public V get ( K key ) {
        return map ( key ).get ( key );
    }

    //For testing only
    @Override
    public V getSilent ( K key ) {
        return map ( key ).getSilent ( key );

    }

    @Override
    public void remove ( K key ) {
        map ( key ).remove ( key );
    }

    @Override
    public int size () {
        int size = 0;
        for ( CacheMap<K, V> cache : cacheRegions ) {
            size += cache.size ();
        }
        return size;
    }

    public String toString () {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
        for ( CacheMap<K, V> cache : cacheRegions ) {
            builder.append ( cache.toString () ).append ( '\n' );
        }

        return builder.toString ();
    }


}
```

You can see why I cover the non-concurrent version first. The above attempts to create some stripes to reduce lock contention. So we it hashes the key and then looks up that hash to find the actual cache. This makes the limit size more of a suggestion/rough guess within a fair amount of error depending on how well spread your keys hash algorithm is.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Statement :**

Create LRU cache and store Employee object Max =5 objects and find out who login first and after ….

```
package com.test.example.dto;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
/**
 * 
 * @author Vaquar.khan@gmail.com
 *
 */
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    private int     id;
    private String  name;
    private int     age;
    private Timestamp loginTime ;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Timestamp getLoginTime() {
    return loginTime;
}

public void setLoginTime(Timestamp loginTime) {
    this.loginTime = loginTime;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", loginTime=" + loginTime + "]";
}

Employee(){}

public Employee(int id, String name, int age, Timestamp loginTime) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.loginTime = loginTime;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + age;
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result + ((loginTime == null) ? 0 : loginTime.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (age != other.age) return false;
    if (id != other.id) return false;
    if (loginTime == null) {
        if (other.loginTime != null) return false;
    } else if (!loginTime.equals(other.loginTime)) return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null) return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
    if (emp.getLoginTime().before( this.loginTime) ){
        return 1;
    } else if (emp.getLoginTime().after(this.loginTime)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


}
```

LRUObjectCacheExample

```
package com.test.example;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import com.test.example.dto.Employee;
/**
 * 
 * @author Vaquar.khan@gmail.com
 *
 */
public class LRUObjectCacheExample {


    LinkedHashMap<Employee, Boolean>    lruCacheLinkedQueue;

public LRUObjectCacheExample(int capacity) {
    lruCacheLinkedQueue = new LinkedHashMap<Employee, Boolean>(capacity, 1.0f, true) {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(
                //calling map's entry method
                Map.Entry<Employee, Boolean> eldest) {
            return this.size() > capacity;
        }
    };
}

void addDataIntoCache(Employee employee) {
    lruCacheLinkedQueue.put(employee, true);
    displayLRUQueue();
}

boolean checkIfDataPresentIntoLRUCaache(int data) {
    return lruCacheLinkedQueue.get(data) != null;
}

 void deletePageNo(int data) {
    if (lruCacheLinkedQueue.get(data) != null){
            lruCacheLinkedQueue.remove(data);
    }
    displayLRUQueue();
}

 void displayLRUQueue() {
    System.out.print("-------------------------------------------------------"+"\n");
    System.out.print("Data into LRU Cache : ");
    for (Entry<Employee, Boolean> mapEntry : lruCacheLinkedQueue.entrySet()) {
        System.out.print("[" + mapEntry.getKey() + "]");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Employee employee1 = new Employee(1,"Shahbaz",29, getCurrentTimeStamp());
    Employee employee2 = new Employee(2,"Amit",35,getCurrentTimeStamp());
    Employee employee3 = new Employee(3,"viquar",36,getCurrentTimeStamp());
    Employee employee4 = new Employee(4,"Sunny",20,getCurrentTimeStamp());
    Employee employee5 = new Employee(5,"sachin",28,getCurrentTimeStamp());
    Employee employee6 = new Employee(6,"Sneha",25,getCurrentTimeStamp());
    Employee employee7 = new Employee(7,"chantan",19,getCurrentTimeStamp());
    Employee employee8 = new Employee(8,"nitin",22,getCurrentTimeStamp());
    Employee employee9 = new Employee(9,"sanuj",31,getCurrentTimeStamp());
    //
    LRUObjectCacheExample lru = new LRUObjectCacheExample(5);
    lru.addDataIntoCache(employee5);//sachin
    lru.addDataIntoCache(employee4);//Sunny
    lru.addDataIntoCache(employee3);//viquar
    lru.addDataIntoCache(employee2);//Amit
    lru.addDataIntoCache(employee1);//Shahbaz -----capacity reached
    //
        lru.addDataIntoCache(employee6);/Sneha
        lru.addDataIntoCache(employee7);//chantan
        lru.addDataIntoCache(employee8);//nitin
        lru.addDataIntoCache(employee9);//sanuj
        //
        lru.deletePageNo(3);
        lru.deletePageNo(4);

    }
    private static Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp(){
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
    }

}
```

**Results:**

```
**Data into LRU Cache :** 
[Employee [id=1, name=Shahbaz, age=29, loginTime=2015-10-15 18:47:28.1
[Employee [id=6, name=Sneha, age=25, loginTime=2015-10-15 18:47:28.125
[Employee [id=7, name=chantan, age=19, loginTime=2015-10-15 18:47:28.125
[Employee [id=8, name=nitin, age=22, loginTime=2015-10-15 18:47:28.125
[Employee [id=9, name=sanuj, age=31, loginTime=2015-10-15 18:47:28.125
```

Answer (score 1):

LinkedHashMap allows you to override the removeEldestEntry function so that whenever a put is executed, you can specify whether to remove the oldest entry or not, thus allowing implementation of an LRU.

```
myLRUCache = new LinkedHashMap<Long,String>() {
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) 
{ 
if(this.size()>1000)
    return true;
  else
      return false;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For O(1) access we need a hash table and to maintain order we can use DLL.
Basic algo is - from page number we can get to DLL node using hash table. If page exists we can move the node to the head of DLL else insert the node in DLL and hash table. If the size of DLL is full we can remove the least recently used node from tail.

Here is an implementation based on doubly linked list and unordered_map in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

// List nodeclass
class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};

//Doubly Linked list
class DLList
{
    public:

    DLList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        count = 0;
    }

    ~DLList() {}

    Node* addNode(int val);
    void print();
    void removeTail();
    void moveToHead(Node* node);

    int size()
    {
        return count;
    }

    private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int count;
};

// Function to add a node to the list

Node* DLList::addNode(int val)
{
    Node* temp = new Node();

    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;

    if ( tail == NULL )
    {
        tail = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        head->prev = temp;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    count++;

    return temp;
}

void DLList::moveToHead(Node* node)
{
    if (head == node)
        return;

    node->prev->next = node->next;

    if (node->next != NULL)
    {
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
    }
    else
    {
        tail = node->prev;
    }
        node->next = head;
        node->prev = NULL;
        head->prev = node;
        head = node;
}

void DLList::removeTail()
{
    count--;

    if (head == tail)
    {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* del = tail;
        tail = del->prev;
        tail->next = NULL;
        delete del;
    }
}

void DLList::print()
{
    Node* temp = head;

    int ctr = 0;

    while ( (temp != NULL) && (ctr++ != 25) )
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

class LRUCache
{
    public:
        LRUCache(int aCacheSize);
        void fetchPage(int pageNumber);

    private:
        int cacheSize;
        DLList dlist;
        unordered_map< int, Node* > directAccess;
};

    LRUCache::LRUCache(int aCacheSize):cacheSize(aCacheSize) { }

    void LRUCache::fetchPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        unordered_map< int, Node* >::const_iterator it = directAccess.find(pageNumber);

        if (it != directAccess.end())
        {
            dlist.moveToHead( (Node*)it->second);
        }
        else
        {
            if (dlist.size() == cacheSize-1)
               dlist.removeTail();

            Node* node = dlist.addNode(pageNumber);

            directAccess.insert(pair< int, Node* >(pageNumber,node));
        }

        dlist.print();
    }

    int main()
    {
        LRUCache lruCache(10);

        lruCache.fetchPage(5);
        lruCache.fetchPage(7);
        lruCache.fetchPage(15);
        lruCache.fetchPage(34);
        lruCache.fetchPage(23);
        lruCache.fetchPage(21);
        lruCache.fetchPage(7);
        lruCache.fetchPage(32);
        lruCache.fetchPage(34);
        lruCache.fetchPage(35);
        lruCache.fetchPage(15);
        lruCache.fetchPage(37);
        lruCache.fetchPage(17);
        lruCache.fetchPage(28);
        lruCache.fetchPage(16);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Peter Lawrey's answer

The `removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)` method may be overridden to impose a policy for removing stale mappings automatically when new mappings are added to the map.

So LinkedHashMap's FIFO behavior can be overriden to make LRU

```
public class LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {

    private int cacheSize;

    public LRUCache(int cacheSize) {
        super(cacheSize * 4 / 3, 0.75f, true);
        this.cacheSize = cacheSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() >= cacheSize;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LRUCache<Integer, Integer> lruCache = new LRUCache<>(5);

        lruCache.put(1, 1);
        lruCache.put(2, 2);
        lruCache.put(3, 3);
        lruCache.put(1, 4);
        lruCache.put(2, 5);
        lruCache.put(7, 6);

        System.out.println(lruCache.keySet());

        lruCache.put(1, 4);
        lruCache.put(2, 5);

        System.out.println(lruCache.keySet());
    }
}
```

Comment: same comment :  eldest entry could be most recently used also. we need to remove least recently used and not eldest entry

Comment: you get access order (i.e. lru) by setting access order flag
LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)

Comment: Agree .. Take back my comment

Answer (score 0):

```
class LRU {
    Map<String, Integer> ageMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int age = 1;

    void addElementWithAge(String element) {

        ageMap.put(element, age);
        age++;

    }

    String getLeastRecent(Map<String, Integer> ageMap) {
        Integer oldestAge = (Integer) ageMap.values().toArray()[0];
        String element = null;
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : ageMap.entrySet()) {
            if (oldestAge >= entry.getValue()) {
                oldestAge = entry.getValue();
                element = entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return element;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LRU obj = new LRU();
        obj.addElementWithAge("M1");
        obj.addElementWithAge("M2");
        obj.addElementWithAge("M3");
        obj.addElementWithAge("M4");
        obj.addElementWithAge("M1");
    }

}
```