# Need Suggestion, to start developing a cache application in java

Tags: java, caching, dictionary, hashmap, in-memory

I know this is a subjective question, I tried to  google out, and went through the documention of different cache providers such as ehcache etc.

Use Case/ Problem Statment: An application(cache application) which will be in different VM of the server, and multiple applications such as Application A, B, C resides in different VM, can communicate to the cache application similar to the concept of Sqlfire/gmfire i.e in memory cache.

Approach:
Note: Considering the requirment, I don't wanna to make use of existing cache mechanisms such mmcache,ehaceh and etc,

Could you please give some idea from where I should start such as:

1-Make use of HashMap/ConcurrentHashMap will be correct approach for this or not?
2-How I can achieve diffrent VMs communicating 
3-Some best practice I should follow as a beginer.
4-went thorugh various questions posted here one of the such link is [Develop in Memory Object Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912883/develop-in-memory-object-cache)

Still in confuse how I can achieve different VMs talking to this cache VM.

I may not be clear enough to put the rough idea I am thinking of, Please let me know if you require further clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Different VM's communicating with each other, you can use RMI, Web-Services, Rest-Services. Using RMI, you will be bound to use Java as the other communicating party. Whereas, web-service and rest-web-services will give you the advantage of using .NET, Java or other as cache clients.

**For a start:**

Use of collections, you can go with ConcurrentHashMap if you have a lot of read and writes, this will still be better performing.

You should consider following more params:

- memory management
- elements aging
- eviction policies

But reinventing the wheel is not a good idea if there is nothing different or better to deliver.

You also need to consider, the cache app doesn't run out of memory, because of too much caching.