# LinkedHashMap Structure for LRU Cache

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I am a little confused about how to build a LRU cache by using LinkedHashMap ([How would you implement an LRU cache in Java 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221525/how-would-you-implement-an-lru-cache-in-java-6)), and I want to make sure I understand how it work internally behind the scene.

Lets say I define a class LRUMap that extends the LinkedHashMap and override the `removeEldestEntry(final Map.Entry<A, B> eldest)` just like the way it is.

Then I construct the data structure and insert 4 items into the map

```
    LRUMap<String,String> map = new LRUMap<String,String>(3); //capacity 3
    map.put("a", "a");
    map.put("b", "b");
    map.put("c", "c");
    map.put("d", "d");
```

and interally `LinkedHashMap` uses an `Entry object` called `header` as a starting node to link with all the items that you add to the map. So in this case it will be

```
   [header] ->  ["a"] -> ["b"] -> ["c"] -> ["d"] -> [header]
```

The header Entry object is both the start and the end of the doubly linked list since header.before = header.after = header when it initially constructs.

And lets say the map reaches the maximum Entries (3 items) that I want it to be, and from

```
    Entry<K,V> eldest = header.after;
    if (removeEldestEntry(eldest)) {
         removeEntryForKey(eldest.key);
    }
    .....
```

So does that mean it will remove ["a"] first ?
And when we call `get(Object key)` does it rearrange the list order where it puts that key (lets say "b") before the header node, so it becomes

```
     [header] ->  ["c"] -> ["d"] -> ["b"] -> [header]
```

Just want to clarify that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Yes; the entry `<"a", "a">` will be removed first :-)
2. Maybe; `LinkedHashMap` by default uses *insertion-order*, not *access-order*...
   straight from [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

   > Hash table and linked list implementation of the `Map` interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from `HashMap` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*).

   That being said, `LinkedHashMap` also supports *access-order*;

   > A special [`constructor`](http://goo.gl/3Ts4p) is provided to create a linked hash map whose order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last accessed, from least-recently accessed to most-recently (*access-order*). This kind of map is well-suited to building LRU caches. Invoking the `put` or `get` method results in an access to the corresponding entry (assuming it exists after the invocation completes).

   So, if you're using *insertion-order*, then the order will not change from `get("b")`; if you're using *access-order* (which generally an LRU cache **would** ;-) then the order *will* change.

Any other questions? :-)

Comment: @user1389813 since you appear newer here, please don't forget to mark the answer [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped most in solving the problem.

Comment: Just wondering can we use this same strategy for LFU cache ? or any other data structure that you would prefer ?

Comment: @user1389813 no, there's probably not a straightforward generic way to implement an LFU cache using `LinkedHashMap` :-/ That being said, generally, the least-frequently-used element has an innate tendency to be the least-recently-used one.