# Get a Character Values from a Map and add all to a String

Tags: java, dictionary, functional-programming, java-stream

I was wondering how i can get these values and put it together in a new String

```
class Rna {


    static Map<Character, Character> map = (Map<Character, Character>) Map.of(
            'G', 'C',
            'C', 'G',
            'T', 'A',
            'A', 'U'
    );

    String transcribe(String dnaStrand) {
        return dnaStrand.chars()
                .map(c -> map.get(c))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint ,StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

transcribe should return an String like "AUGC". Now i`m getting this exception.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please include what you've tried, what results you are getting and examples of what you are expecting. I suggest [writing a unit test](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview) as its results will help you while you experiment with the `transcribe` method.

Comment: Please replace screenshot with text; images are not searchable.

Comment: That screen shot is very hard to read.  Please paste the entire stack trace as text instead.

Comment: Downvoting because the exception is provided as a screenshot instead of as text.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you use the `String.chars()` method which returns a stream of `int`s but you cannot expect autoboxing of an `int` to a  `Character`.

The map doesn't contain `Integer` keys, so always will return `null` for the get.

As a solution you could try to cast c to a char or even create a `Character` instance manually:

`.map(c -> map.get((char)c))` or `.map(c -> map.get(Character.valueof((char)c))`

Comment: the only necessary part is downcasting to `char`, the compiler does the rest. hence this code `Character.valueOf()` is redundant

Answer (score 3):

## `char` obsolete

The `char` primitive type, and its wrapper class `Character`, have been legacy since Java 2. As a 16-bit value, these types are physically incapable of representing most characters.

Avoid `char`/`Character` types.

## Code points

Instead, use [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to work with individual characters.

Your code is mixing `char` values with code point code. Do not mix the types. Avoid `char`, use only code points.

Unfortunately, Java lacks a type for code points. So we use the `int`/`Integer` with several methods awkwardly spread out across various classes including `String`, `StringBuilder`, and `Character`.

```
Map< Integer , Integer > transMap = 
    Map.of(
        "G".codePointAt(0) , "C".codePointAt(0) ,
        "C".codePointAt(0) , "G".codePointAt(0) ,
        "T".codePointAt(0) , "A".codePointAt(0) ,
        "A".codePointAt(0) , "U".codePointAt(0) 
    )
;
```

The transcription method swaps integers. Then collect these integers using `StringBuilder#appendCodePoints`.

By the way, your `transcribe` method could be made more general by taking an parameter of type `CharSequence` rather than `String`. `CharSequence` is an interface implemented by `String`.  The only method we need to call on the argument is `codePoints`. That method is required by `CharSequence`.

```
String transcribe( final CharSequence dnaStrand ) {
    return 
        dnaStrand
        .codePoints()
        .map( codePoint -> transMap.get( codePoint ) )
        .collect(
            StringBuilder :: new, 
            StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint, 
            StringBuilder :: append 
        )
        .toString() ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `char`/`Character` limitations.
In this very specific question, transcribing DNA to RNA can be done using ASCII only: they're made of 4-5 nucleotides, each encoded to a latin letter from the question's `map`.

Comment: @pyb While you are correct technically in the specific case of these five characters, there is **no benefit to using `char`** rather than code points. By making a habit of writing code for code points, you’ll avoid having obscure failures at runtime when your app encounters a character outside the [Unicode basic plane](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

Comment: I agree, the operation should be written to consistently use codepoints. It is already using `StringBuilder::appendCodePoint` for simplicity. Using a `Map<Integer,Integer>` also allows to write `.map(transMap::get)`, as no conversions happen anymore. So, also using `dnaStrand.codePoints()` is consistent. But I wouldn’t write the constants, which are clearly ASCII letters, in such a verbose way. Even `Map<Integer, Integer> transMap = Map.of((int)'G', (int)'C', (int)'C', (int)'G', (int)'T', (int)'A', (int)'A', (int)'U');` would be simpler.

Comment: Further note that the first Java version allowing to assume that `char` is legacy, is Java 5. Earlier versions lack the APIs to deal with codepoints. And perhaps, `static final int A = 'A', C = 'C', G = 'G', T = 'T', U = 'U'; static final Map<Integer, Integer> DNA_RNA = Map.of(G,C, C,G, T,A, A,U);` is even more readable than the variant of my previous comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.  The method is called with a string of keys from your `base/pair` map. Any characters in that string map to `null` are filtered out. This presumes a map instance visible to the method.  Otherwise it will need to be provided as an argument.

- `chars()` provides a stream of characters
- get the mapping for current character and convert to String
- filter out any null values.
- join String characters into long strand and return.

```
static String transcribe(String dnaStrand) {
    return dnaStrand.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf(map.get((char)c)))
            .filter(str->!str.equals("null"))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}

System.out.println(transcribe("GCTA"));
```

will return and print

```
CGAU
```

Answer (score 2):

Method **`get()`** of the **Map** interface accepts an argument of **Object** type as a parameter. Hence you can pass to it an instance of pretty much any type. Not necessarily of the type that matches the type the key. In such a case map will return **null**.

And that's basically what you are doing. Method [**`chars()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()) of the String class returns **IntStream** a stream primitive `int` values (note there is **NO** such thing as `CharStream` in java). Attempt to get a value from a `Map<Character, Character>` result in **null** because the map will look for the object of type **`Integer`**, and obviously, there will be no match.

Instead, you have to `cast` **`int`** to **`char`** `explicitly` and it'll be autoboxed into Character wrapper type.

Also, note that for any given string that contains any other character apart from uppercase `'G', 'C', 'T', 'A'` your code will fail with **`NullPointerException`**.

If a fail-fast implementation wasn't your intent as a workaround you can use [**`map.getOrDefault()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) instead of **`map.get()`**.

Method **`getOrDefault()`** returns a `default value` instead of **null** for any key that isn't represented in the map.

For instance, using `getOrDefault()` you can preserve only characters that are contained in the map and eliminate all others by providing a default value that will be removed from the final string (like that **`getOrDefault((char) c, '!'))`**, and then apply **`replace("!", "")`** to the result).

Another possible option that can be achieved with `getOrDefault()`is to change only those characters in the string that are contained in the map whilst others will remain intact as it's shown in the example below.

```
    public String transcribe(String dnaStrand) {
        return dnaStrand.chars()
                .map(c -> map.getOrDefault((char) c, (char) c))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
                        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, 
                        StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();
    }
```

Comment: I don’t think that using `getOrDefault`, to silently getting wrong results in the case of errors, is an improvement over getting exception in the case of errors.

Comment: @Holger I agree this advice isn't applicable to a practical scenario. As the code snippet provided by PO rather seems to be created for learning purposes my intention was to introduce possible options on how to play around with this code. I've changed my comment to make it more clear.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to obtain map value, you can not have a String like `"AUGC"`, may be `"UAGC"`?
And you can read more about [Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623129/when-to-use-linkedhashmap-over-hashmap-in-java), `Map` and `LinkedHashMap`.
If you will try this code, all will be work.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Map<Character, Character> map = new LinkedHashMap();
            map.put('G', 'C');
        map.put( 'C', 'G');
                map.put( 'T', 'A');
                        map.put( 'A', 'U');


Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.transcribe(map));
    }
}
public class Test {

    String transcribe(Map<Character, Character> map) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Character ch : map.values()) {
            stringBuilder.append(ch);
        }
        return String.valueOf(stringBuilder.reverse());
    }
}
```

Comment: From the name of the classes and method, and the `transcribe` implementation, it seems the question is about translating (mapping) each character of a string one by one. So that `ATCG` gives `UAGC`.