# Any built-in scala cache feature with size limit

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Is there any built LRU Memory cache class in scala with a size limit and key eviction based on LRU/LFU? I've tried https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/caching.html but it seems to be a bit complicated with wrapped futures.

Thanks.

Comment: if you want this to be thread-safe (probably) and referential transparent (maybe), go the `Cats Effect` way: https://gist.github.com/ChristopherDavenport/8364fa2ca14557fce12baca6cb38d5b8That is, if you're already invested in the ecosystem. If not you're probably put off by this example, and you could have a look at a Java library maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772102/lru-cache-in-java-with-generics-and-o1-operations

Answer (score 1):

Caffeine should be a good way to do that : https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine

Comment: I have tried scaffeine, but getting this error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/github/blemale/scaffeine/CacheLoaderAdapter has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: Caffeine 3+ is for java 11, for java 8, you should use caffeine 2+, the latest being 2.9.2